# how do i rewrite a .asp with %C2%A0 in url

Tags: asp.net, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have changed my website and would like to rewrite the following link:

```
mysite.co.uk/productdetails/617/6/Casio%C2%A0CDP120%20Digital%20Piano%20in%20Black/
```

to

```
mysite.co.uk/Casio-CDP120-Digital-Piano-in-Black/302
```

the problem is the `%C2%A0` used to be `%20` don't know why this has changed but when it was %20 I could rewrite it like so:

```
RewriteRule "^productdetails/617/6/Casio CDP120 Digital Piano in Black/?$" /Casio-CDP120-Digital-Piano-in-Black/302 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Other urls are:

```
mysite.co.uk/productdetails/647/6/Casio%20PX350%20Digital%20Piano%20in%20Black/
```

to

```
mysite.co.uk/Casio-PX350-Digital-Piano-in-Black/296
```

these ones i rewrite as follows:
`RewriteRule "^productdetails/647/6/Casio PX350 Digital Piano in Black/?$" /Casio-PX350-Digital-Piano-in-Black/296 [L,NC,R=301`]
There is a mixture of these kind of urls (the last number will be different for each product.

Any help welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following 3 rules will take care of this issue of this weird URL rewriting. Place it into your root .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# take care of %C2%A0
RewriteRule ^(.+)\xc2\xa0(.+)$ $1-$2 [L,NE]

# executes **repeatedly** as long as there are more than 1 spaces in URI
RewriteRule "^(\S*) +(\S* .*)$" $1-$2 [L,NE]

# executes when there is exactly 1 space in URI 
RewriteRule "^productdetails/617/6/(\S*) (\S*?)/?$" /$1-$2/302 [L,R=302,NE]

RewriteRule "^productdetails/647/6/(\S*) (\S*?)/?$" /$1-$2/296 [L,R=302,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however if i leave the RewriteRule "^productdetails/617/6/Casio CDP120 Digital Piano in Black/?$" /Casio-CDP120-Digital-Piano-in-Black/302 [L,NC,R=301] in and add your three rewrite rules i get the following 404 error /productdetails/617/6/Casio-CDP120-Digital-Piano-in-Black/302

Comment: You need to comment out your `RewriteRule "^productdetails/61....` rule and test with these 3 rules only.

Comment: thanks again for your reply, however the same 404 error  /productdetails/617/6/Casio-CDP120-Digital-Piano-in-Black/302 not found. It needs to become /Casio-CDP120-Digital-Piano-in-Black/302

Comment: Great thanks again so much that did the trick, just one quick question can I apply this kind of rule to more of similar urls obviously i need to rewrite the RewriteRule "^productdetails/617/6/(\S*) (\S*?)/?$" /$1-$2/302 [L,R=302,NE] for each, but do i need to do repeat the rule that takes care of the %C2%A0 and the other that takes care of the spaces. for each url? Thanks again so much for your help

Comment: If you give me example of other URLs may be I can tweak this last `302` to make it generic to save you writing individual rules

Comment: I have edited the question with more urls however once the new rewrite rule is in the htaccess the second one doesn't work anymore

Comment: oh but you want a different trailing number in new URL. Earlier it was `302` and now it is 296. That cannot be handled in a single generic rule.

Comment: that is ok i'am willing to write what ever it takes to get it right for every product. It is just for some reason the %C2%A0 replaced the %20 in some of the urls otherwise i would have stuck with the second rule i've got. sorry to keep asking you.

Comment: I have updated answer to suggest you you need to write individual rules for all these cases.

Comment: if you have some time would you be able to help me with the next step I've added a new rewrite rule which used to work, however when I added the above this stopped. here I've posted the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25814592/combination-of-rewrites-in-htaccess-doesnt-work

Comment: sorry to ask you again but I have another question with these strange spaces asked:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865713/rewrite-a-url-with-one-non-breaking-space-in-htaccess If you have some time to look at this. thank you so much