# Combination of rewrites in .htaccess doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have different rules in my .htaccess file which work fine individually but combined in one file they don't.
Here are some examples of my file:

```
# take care of %C2%A0
RewriteRule ^(.+)\xc2\xa0(.+)$ $1-$2 [L,NE]

# executes **repeatedly** as long as there are more than 1 spaces in URI
RewriteRule "^(\S*) +(\S* .*)$" $1-$2 [L,NE]

# executes when there is exactly 1 space in URI 
RewriteRule "^productdetails/617/6/(\S*) (\S*?)/?$" /$1-$2/302 [L,R=302,NE]
```

Also I've got the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pid=617/?$
RewriteRule ^productdetails\.asp$  /Casio-CDP120-Digital-Piano-in-Black/302? [L,NC,R=301]
```

which still work fine.
I have now added the following:

```
RewriteRule "^categories/3/Kawai Digital Pianos/?$" /Compare/Kawai-Digital-Pianos [L,NC,R=301]
```

which used to rewrite:

```
mysite.co.uk/categories/3/Kawai%20Digital%20Pianos/ to mysite.co.uk/Compare/Kawai-Digital-Pianos
```

this does not work anymore

Any help to get the last rule working in combination with the others would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make sure order of rules is correct. For your examples following order should work:

```
RewriteRule "^categories/3/Kawai Digital Pianos/?$" /Compare/Kawai-Digital-Pianos [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pid=617/?$
RewriteRule ^productdetails\.asp$  /Casio-CDP120-Digital-Piano-in-Black/302? [L,NC,R=301]

# take care of %C2%A0
RewriteRule ^(.+)\xc2\xa0(.+)$ $1-$2 [L,NE]

# executes **repeatedly** as long as there are more than 1 spaces in URI
RewriteRule "^(\S*) +(\S* .*)$" $1-$2 [L,NE]

# executes when there is exactly 1 space in URI 
RewriteRule "^productdetails/617/6/(\S*) (\S*?)/?$" /$1-$2/302 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Fantastic that is working a treat. Thanks again so much for your help today. It would otherwise have been a long late sleepless night.