# Rewrite a url with one non-breaking space in .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following url (there are a few like these):

```
mysite.co.uk/productdetails/408/20/Casio%C2%A0CTK1100/
```

and I want to rewrite it to:

```
mysite.co.uk/Casio-CTK1100-in-Black/393
```

The problem is this funny %C2%A0
now I have other links with multiple spaces in there and they are rewritten as follows:

```
# take care of %C2%A0
RewriteRule ^(.+)\xc2\xa0(.+)$ $1-$2 [L,NE]

# executes **repeatedly** as long as there are more than 1 spaces in URI
RewriteRule "^(\S*) +(\S* .*)$" $1-$2 [L,NE]
RewriteRule "^productdetails/617/6/(\S*) (\S*?)/?$" /$1-$2/302 [L,R=302,NE] (is just and example of a url with more than 1 space)
```

This works prefect, however when the url only has one space in it like the one shown above it will not work. I will need to keep the above rule in my .htaccess file to be able to rewrite the urls with multiple space.

Any help welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have it like this:

```
# take care of %C2%A0
RewriteRule ^(.+)\xc2\xa0(.+)$ $1-$2 [L,NE]

# executes **repeatedly** as long as there are more than 1 spaces in URI
RewriteRule "^(\S*) +(\S* .*)$" $1-$2 [L,NE]

RewriteRule "^productdetails/617/6/(\S*) (\S*?)/?$" /$1-$2/302 [L,R=302,NE]

RewriteRule "^productdetails/408/20/(\S+?)/?$" /$1-in-Black/393 [L,R=302,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is not quite working it is looking for /Casio-CTK1100/-in-Black/393 instead of /Casio-CTK1100-in-Black/393 for some reason it put a / in after CTK1100